# Amazon Web Service SDK iOS

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I've been stuck trying to use the AWS with iOS for 2 days now. I downloaded the example project from here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples

I did exactly as the steps said, I used cocoapods to link all the libraries.

I also created a bucket and again followed the steps on how to get the ID in order to change it within the code as seen below:

```
AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
                                                      credentialsWithRegionType:AWSRegionUSEast1
                                                      accountId:AWSAccountID
                                                      identityPoolId:CognitoPoolID
                                                      unauthRoleArn:CognitoRoleUnauth
                                                      authRoleArn:nil];
```

So basically when Im trying to upload some images/files (in the example  using the S3 Storage Service by Amazon, I get an error:

```
2014-09-04 15:11:57.475 S3TransferManagerSample[5437:400b] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m
  line:356 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke299 | Unable to refresh. 
  Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain error 0.)" 
   UserInfo=0x14d17770 {Type=Sender, Message=Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, __text=(
"\n    ",
"\n    ",
"\n    ",
"\n  "
), Code=AccessDenied}]
```

Just to be clear, I've already created a role and gave it a policy:AdministratorAccess and used the Role ARN to set the

```
unauthRoleArn:CognitoRoleUnauth
```

I've read the documentation and can't seem to find the problem anywhere. I have a feeling it has something to do with the role and the policy given to the role.

I'd really appreciate any tips on how to get started or how to fix this problem.

Thanks, and if you need more details about the question feel free to comment and I'll give more, as the question got a bit lengthy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the error you are experiencing is due to the **trust relations** in your role, not the permissions for the credentials on the role.

You must make sure your role's trust relationships:

1. Trust the identity pool you are using (the **aud** matches the identity pool id).
2. Trust identities with the supplied authentication (the **amr** matches *unauthenticated* or *authenticated* depending on your use case).

Take care when modifying roles created during the setup wizard or reusing roles as these 2 values may not match and generate the error above.

You may also find [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) helpful in understanding how Cognito Authentication works.

Comment: When I created the role I only changed the permissions of that role to Administrator Access, I did not change anything else.

Should I change the trust relations of the role? I don't really know what to set it to.

Comment: Also, what do you mean if it was "for this identity pool"? I created the identity pool as part of the Cognito service, while the roles are set up in the IAM management console. I've read a lot of things regarding AWS, and I think I'm getting a bit confused. Sorry if I seem a bit unclear. Thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my current Identity Pool and created a new one, the error I was getting is gone. But now its not uploading the files, I'm getting another error now while trying to upload:

Comment: _error NSError * domain: @"com.amazonaws.AWSS3ErrorDomain" - code: 1 0x16786df0

Comment: @RJiryes Please create a new question and post your code and any debug logs that show the full error.

Comment: How did this answer solve the issue @BobKinney? I'm experiencing the same issue and simply deleting and re-creating the identity pool shouldn't be the solution. My roles were created from the setup wizard and I simply added S3PutObject action to a specific bucket.

Comment: @Miles, I wasn't trying to suggest that this was the only way to solve the problem. You must make sure that your role trust relationships trust the identity pool and the type of authentication. [This blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2UQN4KWI6GDJL/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication) may help clarify.

Comment: @Miles, I've updated the answer to reflect the underlying values STS validates. Hope this clarifies. If not, please feel free to post a new question with details of your problem.

Comment: @BobKinney thanks for the response. my issue was actually unrelated: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=162030&tstart=0